# Windows touch interfering with AIR

Tags: mobile, windows-8, air, touch, windows-8.1

I'm developing a multi-platform AIR app here.
I have things on the screen, that can be dragged around, activated by long-tapping on them.
This works fine on all systems except Windows 8(.1)

When long-tapping, Windows opens a rectangle for marking a selection and prevents the MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN from beeing fired.

Is there any way to perhibit this for an air app?

Thanks, as always any input is welcome.
Timm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try switching to using TouchEvent's instead of MouseEvent's which tend to face issues with a touch-enabled OS such as Windows 8.1 (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa93023c59dfc1257b16a3d6-7ffe.html)

```
something.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, onTap);
```

There is also

```
MultiTouch.mapTouchToMouse = false
```

which might prevent Windows from firing its own reaction to something like a long tap.

Also, be sure you are using the latest version of AIR (AIR14 at the time of this writing) as bugs with Multitouch have been resolved in most recent versions.

You can find instructions for overlaying the latest version of AIR here:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/overlay-air-sdk-flash-builder.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will try this as soon as possible and give feedback again. It might take a while, though, as I'm in holidays right now. (hooray!) ;-)